# Realm.framework/Headers No such file or directory

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, realm

```
ln: It/BuildProductsPath/Release/Realm/Realm.framework/Headers: No such file or directory
ln: It/BuildProductsPath/Release/Realm/Realm.framework/PrivateHeaders: No such file or directory
```

I can build & run the project, but when I am trying to archive the project, it shows me this error. I have tried cleaning up the project and deleting derived data, but that didn't help me.

I am using `Realm` in macOS App. I installed `macOS 10.12.1` and tried archiving the project, then this error appeared. It was working fine in previous macOS version.

Please help me to solve this, Thanks in Advance.

---

I have updated to new cocoa pods [ `Dmitry pointed out` ], now I am using cocoa pods beta version. 
I have installed the beta version using this command `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`. Now the `pod --version` command shows me that the cocoa pods version is `1.2.0.beta.1`. Tried archiving the project again, but the same error appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a CocoaPods issue that was fixed in https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/6146.

Please try to update to the latest CocoaPods [beta] version.

---

Looks like the current beta doesn't include that fix, so for now the workaround I suggest is to simply add missing quotes to your project manually:

1. Select `Pods` project in project navigator
2. Select `Realm` target -> Build Phases
3. Find `Create Symbolic Links to Header Folders` and replace the script to

   ```
   base="$CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/$WRAPPER_NAME"
   ln -fs "$base/${PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH#$WRAPPER_NAME/}" "$base/${PUBLIC_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH#$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/}"
   ln -fs "$base/${PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH#$WRAPPER_NAME/}" "$base/${PRIVATE_HEADERS_FOLDER_PATH#$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH/}"
   ```

Comment: @Dimitry Do you want me to update to the latest [beta] version of CocoaPods ?

Comment: Yes. Fixed the answer. Another option is to add quotes for this paths manually to your Pods->Copy Private Headers build phase.

Comment: I have updated to beta version of cocoa pods, it is not working, showing the same error. I have updated the question, Please take a look.