# Xcode keeps throwing error "No such file or directory" on a video and image files

Tags: swift, xcode

Every time I get that error "No such file or directory", I keep having to deintegrate and do a "pod install" + fresh build. Nothing else helps. Then after I run the project a few times, I get the same error message again.

I tried going to Target (Project) -> Copy Bundle Resources -> ...

...but none of the files are marked in red. Not sure how to fix this.

I also get the same error with Realm pod for some reason.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40934032/realm-framework-headers-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: But in general this seems like an issue to be reported to the realm people or the cocoapods people.